# Why is writing to C array this slow in Cython?

Tags: python, optimization, cython

I have a Cython class like the following somewhat artificial example:

```
cdef class Differential:

  cdef int *SX
  cdef int *X
  cdef int nmax

  def __init__(self, int nmax):

    self.nmax = nmax ## usually around 10*1000

    return

  def __cinit__(self, int nmax, *arg, **args):

    self.SX = <float *>malloc(nmax*cython.sizeof(float))

    ## assume self.X has some content.
    self.X = <float *>malloc(nmax*cython.sizeof(float)) 

    return

  def __dealloc__(self):

    free(self.SX)
    free(self.X)

    return

  @cython.wraparound(False)
  @cython.boundscheck(False)
  @cython.nonecheck(False)
  @cython.cdivision(True)
  cdef void __reject(self, float step) nogil:

    cdef unsigned int v
    cdef unsigned int k

    cdef double x
    cdef double dx

    float_array_init(self.SX,1000,0.) ## writes 0. to the 100000 first elements

    for v in range(1000):

      x = self.X[v]

      for k in range(v+1,1000):

        dx = x-self.X[k]

        # the following line is the "problem":
        self.SX[k] -= dx

    ## some more code
    # manipulate SX some more. this section has less performance impact because it
    # is not a double for-loop, so i have not included it in the example

    # update X
    for v in range(1000):
      self.X[v] += self.SX[v]

def reject(self, float step):
  self.__reject(step)
```

The code is considerably more involved, but I have tried to strip it down to the minimum amount that still illustrates the flow of my code.

In my main script I simply create an instance of Differential and I repeatedly call Differential.reject() (and a few other things in between to actually change the values of X.)

I am aware that I could be using `cpdef` to avoid the extra wrapper call (__reject() and reject()), but my testing indicates that this makes no difference.

My question is the following:

**When I comment out the line `self.SX[k] -= dx` the code seems to speed up by about a factor of 10. Is this to be expected?**

I understand that accessing memory has a cost, but I did not expect the code to slow down that much.

**Update**

As suggested below, changing the lines

```
cdef double x
cdef double dx
```

to

```
cdef float x
cdef float dx
```

Removes the need for some casting operations, and speeds up the code by a factor of about 2.

Comment: Posting (the relevant portions of) the C code that Cython generates would be useful.

Comment: Though it's probably just cache; without that line, the only area of memory used in the double loop is self.X, so it'll most likely remain in cache the whole time. When you add the self.SX line, the amount of heap used doubles, which could push it out of the cache maybe? Depends what the value of nmax is

Comment: I will try to do that later. The problem is that my actual code is much more complex, so stripping it down is a bit difficult. My theory at the moment is also that it is cache, @BluePeppers. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found a problem that may explain the slowness, note that you create `x` and `dx` as `double` to receive `float` values, by changing to:

```
cdef float x
cdef float dx
```

I got a speedup of 2X, since it avoids a casting of float values to double in `x = self.X[v]` followed by a casting from double to float again in `self.SX[k] -= dx`.

It seems your are **not** loosing cache in your approach, I tested using a single array to store the values of both `self.X` and `self.SX` by controlling the access through `2*i+0` or `2*i+1` (`0` for `self.X` and `1` for `self.SX`) and the timing was the same.

Comment: Good catch. I've accepted this as the answer. Thanks for testing!